# A question about a relationship of expressions got from change of variables/inner products

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $F:L^2(S) \to L^2(T)$ is linear homeomorphism such that $F(v) = v \circ \mathcal{F}$ where $\mathcal{F}:T \to S$ is a diffeomorphism. Suppose
$$\lVert F(v) \rVert_{L^2(T)} \leq C\lVert v \rVert_{L^2(S)}.$$
By letting $G = \frac F C$, we see that
$$\lVert G(v) \rVert_{L^2(T)} = \lVert v \rVert_{L^2(S)}.$$
So must $G$ also preserves inner products. So we have 
$$(f,g)_{L^2(S)} = (Gf, Gg)_{L^2(T)} = \frac{1}{C^2}(Ff,Fg)_{L^2(T)}$$
but 
$$(f,g)_S = \int_{S}f(x)g(x) = \int_{T}f(\mathcal{F}(y))g(\mathcal{F}(y))|\text{det}(D\mathcal{F}(y))| = \int_T Ff\cdot Fg|\text{det}(D\mathcal{F}(y))|$$
<del>so the expressions are not equal unless the determinant is constant and equal to $\frac{1}{C^2}$. 
How can this be? Where is my mistake?</del>

**Edit**: typing this out, I realise now that we  don't need the determinant to be that constant since it's being integrated. Is it possible to determine the relationship between the expressions though? I guess letting $f = g$ and $\mathcal{Ff} = 1$ tells us something about the volume. And Jacobians are related to volume in a way. But I still am a bit confused about the role of the constant $C$.